# Why do I get a blank black screen when I try to install Lubuntu 13.04 on a 12" Powerbook?

Tags: 13.04

I thought I'd try Lubuntu out but I'm having problems right off the bat: I get a blank black screen when trying to install.

I created a [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1175736) and I've been searching around more and I've tried a few more boot options like `nouveau.modeset=0` and I still just get a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

During the bootup, press tab, then add the following line in your startup script (before the 2 -- at the end) to see if this helps:

```
nouveau.blacklist=1
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY late post, but I was looking for a solution for this problem while trying to install 15.10 on a G4 15" and I kept finding this post in the process-- I eventually discovered occasionally hitting the F2 (big sunshine) key *without* hitting the function key would eventually wake the screen and keyboard backlights up after the system had finished booting.